# have access to localhost:80 how to get access to localhost:8080 server is ubuntu on VirtualBox need to get access from host machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nginx, npm

Running Ubuntu server on VirtualBox with host-only and Nat networks
can successfully access to Nginx server running on port 80 by :80
getting error when trying to access to :8080/build/app.css,
wget localhost:8080/build/app.css in guest machine successfully works.

Any idea, how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try virtualbox port forwarding?

Comment: If you're using the uncomplicated firewall (`ufw`), then you can permit external traffic to that port with `sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp`. If you're not using the uncomplicated firewall, you may want to include some more specific information about your server configuration, as the current question leaves a lot to be assumed 

Comment: VirtualBox host-only adapter does not have port forwarding.

Comment: firewall is not running. What kind of information can I provide to make question more clear?